# insert key value pairs properly javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working to fix some legacy code. I have made an example and the results will follow. This is an example of the old array.

```
var old = { 1: ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'] };
```

This should be what is returned

```
var expected = { a: 1, e: 1, i: 1, o: 1, u: 1 };
```

Now if I use this

```
var ETL = function(){};

ETL.prototype.transform = function(old){
    var array = [];
    for (var variable in old) {
        console.log(variable);
        for(var i = 0; i < old[variable].length; i++){
            var obj = {};
            var key = old[variable][i].toLowerCase();
            obj[key] = parseInt(variable);
            array.push(obj);
        }
    }
    return array;
};
```

I get this result

```
[ { a : 1 }, { e : 1 }, { i : 1 }, { o : 1 }, { u : 1 } ]
```

Which is really close but not quite what I'm looking for. I think I've created an array of objects when I really just want an object with key value pairs. I think step 1 is to redeclare array as an object, and then step 2 is to rework the code to work with an object instead of an array. I'm just not exactly sure how to do that.

Comment: Yes, use an object, not an array. Then `obj[key] = parseInt(variable)`. And that's all. Get rid of the other superfluous code for `obj` and `push`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var obj = {};
for(var i = 0; i < old[variable].length; i++){

            var key = old[variable][i].toLowerCase();
            obj[key] = parseInt(variable);
            //array.push(obj);
        }
```

Declare obj only once. You are creating it in every iteration of loop

Comment: This worked for me, iterates all the data out correctly into an object

Answer (score 0):

You can use array `reduce` method to resolve it.

```
var old = { 1: ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'] };
var _getOne = old['1']; //get value of key 1

function getWordCnt(arr){
    return arr.reduce(function(prev,next){
        prev[next] = (prev[next] + 1) || 1;
        return prev;
    },{});
}
console.log(getWordCnt(_getOne))
```

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/8n43nsmp/)

Note : Better to have a key as a string instead of an integer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your have many properties of the object each with an array of capital letters the following single line assignment will turn them all into the new form.

```js
var old = { 1: ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'],
            2: ['B', 'T', 'O', 'M', 'V'],
            3: ['C', 'B', 'X', 'N', 'S']
          },
newList = Object.keys(old).map(k => old[k].reduce((p,c) => {p[c.toLowerCase()] = k*1; return p},{}));
document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(newList,null,2) + "</pre>");
```